# How to POST on 3 level with JSONLD & Hydra (Symfony API)

Tags: php, api, symfony, json-ld, hydra-core

I'm actually working on a Symfony REST API and doing some tests for a further project and I need your help.

I have an Entity Contact, which have an array of MoyenCommunication (abstract class with only an id).
I have en Entity Telephone, which inherits from MoyenCommunication and contains a unique property "numero".

```
 Contact -> ($moyenComms)[Telephone->numero]
```

I'd like to test my API and add directly a Contact with a MoyenCommunication that is Telephone with it's "numero".

Here is the Json-LD I try to post :

```
{
"nom": "Nomgfdg",
"prenom": "Prenomgfdgd",
"dateNaissance": "2016-02-16",
"amiDepuis": "2016-02-16",
"moyensComm": [
    {
        "@type": "Telephone",
        "numero": "100009"
     }
     ]
}
```

Here is the Response :

```
 Cannot create an instance of ContactBundle\\Entity\\MoyenCommunication from serialized data because it is an abstract resource
```

Here is my MoyenCommunication mapping :

```
    inheritanceType: JOINED
discriminatorColumn:
    name: type
    type: integer
discriminatorMap:
    1: Telephone
```

I really don't know what i'm doing bad so I need your help.
I already googled but without any good result.
Thank you.
Boris

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear:

```
Cannot create an instance of ContactBundle\Entity\MoyenCommunication from serialized data because it is an abstract resource
```

You need to use non abstract class for resource. Create new class witch will extend MoyenCommunication and use it for your resource representation.

Comment: I already try to use Telephone which extends from MoyenCommunication (look at the code in my query), in fact I don't know WHY it is trying to instantiate a MoyenCommunication.

Comment: But moyensComm is still type of abstract class ContactBundle\Entity\MoyenCommunication. It can't be. Looks like serializer don't play nice with Doctrine discriminators feature.

Comment: Check here how looks proper Abstract class for DunglasApiBundle. It passes fetch/create/update/ tests in bundle https://github.com/dunglas/DunglasApiBundle/blob/9b1005a5774cc7d766cd11e9912e268f25ffe393/Tests/Behat/TestBundle/Entity/AbstractDummy.php so somehow it should be ok. Maybe this will give you some hints.

Comment: so my Contact need to have "telephone" instead of "moyensComm" ? tha'ts not what i need because it will be must simple for me to use an array of moyensComm than searching each inheritence from MoyenCommunication.

Comment: Ok now MoyenCommunication is no more abstract, but i tried to POST that `{
 "nom": "Nomgfdg",
    "prenom": "Prenomgfdgd",
    "dateNaissance": "2016-02-16",
    "amiDepuis": "2016-02-16",
    "moyensComm": [
        {
         "@type": "Telephone",
            "type": "1",
            "numero": "100000009"
         }
         ]
} `and it's telling my that it cannot INSERT type (null) in MoyenCommunication

Comment: something must be wrong now with your MoyenCommunication mapping - as it don't see that you pass correct type.

Comment: contact has a manyToMany relation with MoyenCommunication : 
` manyToMany:
        moyensComm:
            targetEntity: MoyenCommunication
            joinTable:
                name: contact_moyencomm
                joinColumns:
                    contact_id:
                        referencedColumnName: id
            cascade: [ persist, merge, detach ] 
`
In my database and after some tests it seems that my mapping is correct ... i still don't know why it is asking my the "type" for my discriminator